# Records in patterns

Tags: erlang, design-patterns, record

I am learning erlang and I stumbles over some behaviour I cannot quite understand. Take this piece of code. (I know there are existing libraries for what I am programming, but as I stated, I do this for educational purposes):

```
-module (codec).
-compile (export_all).
-record (node, {symbol, weight, order, left, right, parent} ).
-record (tree, {root, nodes} ).

highestOrderForWeight (Weight, Tree) ->
    lists:max ( [Node#node.order || Node <- Tree#tree.nodes, Node#node.weight == Weight] ).

swapMaybe (Node, Tree) ->
    case highestOrderForWeight (Node#node.weight, Tree) of
        Node#node.order -> pass; 
        Node#node.parent -> pass;
        Tree#tree.root -> pass;
        Partner -> io:format ("Swapping ~p with ~p.~n", [Node#node.order, Partner] )
    end.
```

The compiler is not at all amused about my code:

```
./so.erl:11: illegal pattern
./so.erl:12: illegal pattern
./so.erl:13: illegal pattern
error
```

It has appearently some trouble digesting records in patterns, because when I change my code to this clumsy work-around, it compiles fine:

```
swapMaybe2 (Node, Tree) ->
    [Order, Parent, Root] = [Node#node.order, Node#node.parent, Tree#tree.root],
    case highestOrderForWeight (Node#node.weight, Tree) of
        Order -> pass; 
        Parent -> pass;
        Root -> pass;
        Partner -> io:format ("Swapping ~p with ~p.~n", [Node#node.order, Partner] )
    end.
```

**Questions:**

- How do I access record fields in patterns?
- If it is not possible to do so, why is that so?
- If it is not possible to do so, what is the common practice to work around that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually records are just a compile time syntactic sugar and you can look at the actual constructs by using `'E'` [compiler option](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/compile.html#file-2). For example `Node#node.order` will be replaced by something like this:

```
case Node of
    {node,_,_rec0,_,_,_} ->
        rec0;
    _ ->
        error({badrecord,node})
end
```

And of course when you try to use `Node#node.order` as a patter compiler reports `illegal pattern` for this construct.

Your `swapMaybe` function can be rewritten like this:

```
swapMaybe(#node{order=Order, parent=Parent}, Tree=#tree{root=Root}) ->
    case highestOrderForWeight (Weight, Tree) of
        Order -> pass; 
        Parent -> pass;
        Root -> pass;
        Partner -> io:format ("Swapping ~p with ~p.~n", [Order, Partner] )
    end.
```

Comment: Thank you. Why does the second parameter start with `Tree=` but the first does not start with `Node=` ? Or is this a type?

Comment: @Hyperboreus That's optional and it means you have a variable `Tree` representing the whole tree record, at the same time as having decomposed it to get the `Root` variable. You could add `Node=` as well, but the compiler would complain about `Node` being unused.

Comment: The whole `#tree{}` record will be binded to `Tree` variable but there is no need for `Node` variable. You can also pattern match records like this: `funcName(Tree=#tree{})` - in this case you just pattern match the record but don't bind any record variables.

Answer (score 4):

It's indeed not possible to use records in `case` statements the way you did. Pattern matching records works like this:

```
 swapMayBe2(#node{order=Order, parent=Parent, root=Root} = Node, Tree) ->
     ...
```

This binds `Order` to the field `order` etc.

Take a look at the Erlang Programming Examples User's Guide: http://www.erlang.org/doc/programming_examples/records.html#id62786

Answer (score 3):

A pattern is not an arbitrary expression that evaluates to the thing you want to match against - you can't for example write:

```
  case ... of
      1 + 2 -> ...
```

and your attempt to match against the value of a field of a record:

```
  case some_integer(...) of
      Node#node.order -> ...
```

is really just the same kind of thing. A *pattern* always has the form of a constructor - it describes the shape of a thing, not how it is computed. As you noted, pre-instantiated variables can be used:

```
  Order = Node#node.order,
  case some_integer(...) of
      Order -> ...
```

The more common solution is to put the computed value in a guard, if the expression you want is so simple that it's allowed in guards:

```
case some_integer(...) of
    Value when Value =:= Node#node.order -> ...
```

If the expressions are short, you might want to combine them in a single clause, using a semicolon as separator in the guard:

```
case some_integer(...) of
    V when V =:= Node#node.order ; V =:= Node#node.parent ; V =:= Node#node.root ->
        ...;
    Other ->
        ...
end
```

(Finally, as a matter of style, please don't put a space between the function name and the opening parenthesis of the argument list.)